# How to return full path to both folders AND files?

Tags: powershell

I have been tasked with auditing a file server at work, to review directory and file ownership, and subsequent meta data. I have scowered the internet to enable me to string together a script that returns the data required. The script I have created so far is as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -r -Path '\\SERVERNAME.wan.net\launshared\Training' |
    Select DirectoryName, UNC_Path_Parent_DIR, Name, Type, Extension,
        @{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().owner}},
        @{N='SizeInKb';E={$_.Length/1kb}}, CreationTime, LastAccessTime,
        LastWriteTime |
    epcsv 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Information Management\TrainingTEST - 2018- SCRIPT_RESULT.xls' -En UTF8 -NoType -Delim ','
```

Please ignore the `UNC_Path_Parent_DIR` entry, this simply inserts a field header with no returned data in the exported CSV file.

The script works fine, albeit with one exception...it does not return the full UNC path for the directories! Please note, the full UNC path is returned for the files but **NOT** the **directories**!

I have searched the internet for a solution, enquired with our IT guys, however cannot for the life of me locate a solution that will list the full UNC path to both directories AND files.

Comment: Have you tried using `FullName`? It works both for files and folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll leave it here too as additional possible way (although [@DarkLite1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51189470/9902555) answer covers the question quite fully)*.

It's possible that `FullName` will fulfill your needs without any custom expression.

If you use `Get-ChildItem` like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\servername.domain.com\C$\foldername\
```

Then using `| Select FullName` will give you path in the UNC format:

```
\\servername.domain.com\C$\foldername\\FirstSubfolder
```

Keep in mind that it applies only to the situation when you reference the **remote folder**, not folder from the machine you run the script on. If you use `FullName` on local folder you'll get format like this:

```
C:\FolderName\FirstSubfolder
```

Comment: Thanks Robdy. I should have stumbled across this when searching the net for an answer...probably they way I was posing the question when searching. An even simpler solution using one parameter! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The `UNC path` is not a property of the objects coming from `Get-ChildItem`. What this means is that it needs to be added manually. One can do this, just like you did, by adding a custom `property` with an `expression` in `Select-Object`.

Please keep in mind that when others read your code it's always nicer to format things and use the full parameter name. It makes it easier to read and understand, also for you when you read it again in 10 years time ;)

I'll help you on your way by letting you know that you can find the code that gets the `UNC path` [here](https://code.adonline.id.au/unc-path-from-local-path-in-powershell/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/AdamDimech/cc1ec3d59ab6afbef8c70d9ab2154837). The only thing left is to implement it in the correct place within the `Select-Object`. I leave that as an exercise for you:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path '\\fsabbey12.wan.net\launshared\Training' | Select-Object FullName, DirectoryName, 
    Name, Type, Extension, 
    @{N='UNC';E= {  
        # Code to get the UNC Path
    }}, 
    @{N='Owner';E= {$_.GetAccessControl().owner}}, 
    @{N='SizeInKb';E={$_.Length/1kb}}, 
    CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime
```

I think this will get you started.

Comment: Thank you. I have now managed to get it to work using the following, based on your suggestion: @{N='UNC';E={$_.$(get-location).path}}. Your advise regarding formatting and using full parameter names is well received and makes absolute sense. The power of PowerShell is phenominal...my journy is long! Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you out :) You can also check if the property `FullName` is what you meant instead of `UNC path`. In that case you can remove the extra expression and just use `FullName`.